# Change string enclosed in quotes to double quotes

Tags: php, string, quotes

I've got a code like this

```
$str = 'Hello\nThere $foo';
```

and I have to "convert" it like this:

```
$str = "Hello\nThere $foo";
```

Is that possible?

|EDIT| Convert as in parse it. It's being used in a cms and only accepts strings in double-quotes. But problem solved

Comment: Isn't that something your editor's find&replace can do for you?

Comment: convert it programmatically ?? if not you can actually replace `'` with `"`

Comment: Yes, instead of typing the '-character, press Shift before typing it. It will then become a double quote, ". What is the problem? Do you want to replace all occurrences of single quotes in multiple files? Try Notepad++, but beware, it might replace them where you don't want it to.

Comment: Read the comment I wrote to the answer belove. I needed to create a string in single-quotes, if not php would mess with my variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to interpolate the variables/escaped sequences in your string that you already have in memory, try [`eval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php):

```
eval('$str = "'.$str.'";');
```

Comment: Stupid me forgot eval. Worked as a charm. Thanks alot

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just put your pointer before `'`, press `delete` button and after that press `"`

PS: don't forget to escape `$` -> `\$`

Comment: +1, this works for me. You have got to do this for every `'` in your document.

Comment: Haha. Well. The problem is/was that I had to create the string with single-quotes. If I did not the script would mess with my variables. But the cms I am using to parse this script into, was only accepting strings enclosed with double-quotes. The answer belove did it, so thanks :)